Macro for replacing data and then collating it?
Wondering if someone could help create a macro that will both replace information and collate data from a column into a certain format. I'm aware I could use replace and cocat function respectively but the Google spreadsheet is already heavy and I am still learning how to use Apps Script.
Date is generated like so:



Department
Name 
Duration
Pay Code
Request Date




Maintenance
Doe, John
4 hours
PTO
5/30/24



I would like to be able to turn the data into this worksheet (with the specific punctuation):



Subject
Date




Maintenance: Doe, John (4 hours, PTO)
5/30/24



I have tried it with the concat function but unable to get the punctuations just right, so I have to still go in an edit the sheet.

try:
function processSheetData() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  for (let i = 1; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    const a = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
    const b = sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
    const c = sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
    const d = sheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
    const e = sheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue();

    const g = `${a}: ${b}, (${c}, ${d})`;
    const h = e;

    sheet.getRange(i, 7).setValue(g);
    sheet.getRange(i, 8).setValue(h);
  }
}


input A:E
output G:H

or something smarter:
var INPUT_RANGE = 'Sheet1!A2:E10';
var OUTPUT_RANGE = 'Sheet2!B3:C';

function processSheetData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var inputRange = sheet.getRange(INPUT_RANGE);
  var inputData = inputRange.getValues();
  
  var outputData = inputData.map(function(row) {
    var colG = row[0] + ': ' + row[1] + ', (' + row[2] + ', ' + row[3] + ')';
    var colH = row[4];
    return [colG, colH];
  });

  var outputRange = sheet.getRange(OUTPUT_RANGE);
  outputRange.offset(0, 0, outputData.length, outputData[0].length).setValues(outputData);
}


Thank you, I want to follow up and say this was really helpful!
